# How to use an API that requires user's entry (Sentiment Analysis)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, api

I am working "Sentiment Analysis" API: http://text-processing.com/demo/sentiment/ Where you enter a text then click enter, and the result will be the text is positive or negative.

I was able to request the source code. I split the source code and now I am printing only the default text (Where the user has to enter his text). But I am not sure how to run the API now after I entered a text. I mean I want to check whether the text I entered is positive or negative.

```
import requests
url = "http://text-processing.com/demo/sentiment/"
r = requests.get(url)
text = r.text.split('name="text">')[1]
text = text.split('<')[0]
print(text)
```

I read the API docs it says you can do something like this:

```
curl -d "text=great" http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/
```

In python IDE curl is not defined. How can I do something like this in Python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will use python to get the sentiment for any text you enter:

```
import os
import json
result = json.loads(os.popen('curl -d "text=great" http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/').read())
print result['label']
```

However, since "curl is not defined", you need to make sure that you have curl installed. If you are on any operating system, you can install it at https://curl.haxx.se/download.html : 
simply choose your operating and system and install curl. Once you have curl installed, the above code will work. You can simply change the

```
"text = great"
```

part of the code to whatever text you want. 
In my example, this code will print out "pos"; if the text was negative, it would print out "neg". 
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped. Just a small question. Why did you read it as json I think it is in HTML format. Also is there any way to do the same without curl ? Thanks again

Comment: When I printed result,  I got the result {u'probability': {u'neg': 0.3013501976169055, u'neutral': 0.27119050546800266, u'pos': 0.6986498023830945}, u'label': u'pos'}, which is in json format. Since the API shows the command curl in the documentation, I do not think there is an alternative way. I tried adding a parameter "text = great" to the url request but it threw an error.

Comment: Np :) Glad I could help.